# Dynamic Routing not working after build on NextJS 13

Tags: next.js, next.js13, nextjs-dynamic-routing

I am trying to simply show dynamic route pages using the new NextJS 13 Page Router system. It works on dev but after build and serve*ing it locally it throws me a 404 page not found .

[Folder Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fd6jA.png)

[dynamic page content](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gq4Jm.png)

[terminal local deploy command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H9V51.png)

[output on dynamic page route](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iLfxB.png)

I have tried using function

```
getStaticPaths
```

but all seems to do nothing.

Comment: It seems to me that looking at the [official documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing)'s routing section might already suffice for your question.

Comment: Made it work using getStaticPaths. I wasn't using it properly. Also in the next config file i had to add
 **typescript:{
    ignoreBuildErrors:true
  }**